# vsnprintf equivalent for wide strings on Posix based systems

Tags: c, macos, unix, gcc, printf

On Mac OS X (most UNIX based systems),
**vsnprintf** return the number of characters printed (not including the trailing `'\0'` used to end output to strings) OR if an error occurs it returns the number of characters that would have been printed if the n were unlimited(again, not including the final `'\0'`).

On Mac OS X (most UNIX based systems),
The **vswprintf**() functions will fail if n or more wide characters were requested to be written. THIS DOES NOT return the number of characters would have been printed.

ON Windows, 
Ee have below functions that returns the number of characters that would be generated if the string pointed to by the list of arguments was printed or sent to a file or buffer using the specified formatting codes.
**_vsctprintf   _vscprintf  _vscwprintf
_vsctprintf_p   _vscprintf_p    _vscwprintf_p**

**I do not find an alternative for wide strings i.e of _vscwprintf.** Though _vscprintf  can be achieved using vsnprintf and passing NULL and 0 as first two parameters.

Comment: `_vsnwprintf` anyone?

Comment: _vsnwprintf is not on Mac and other UNIX based systems, secondly _vsnwprintf this does not return the number of characters would have been printed, in case the buffer passed was not sufficient as in vsnprintf.

Comment: Are you looking for a Posix equivalent for a Windows function, or is it the other way around?

Comment: I am looking for a function similar to vsnprintf for WIDE strings. Like vsnprintf return the number of characters would have been printed in case I pass first two parameters: a NULL dest buffer and 0 size.

Comment: I see. I don't think such functions exist in any standard.

Comment: It turns out to be harder to simulate _vscwprintf() because the vswprintf() function is not as helpful as the vsnprintf() function. Specifically, vswprintf() reports an error if the formatted string won't fit in the formatted space, whereas vsnprintf() reports the number of characters that would have been needed in the buffer if it was going to fit.